# set bootstrap right side or left side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble to understand how to use bootstrap column RIGHT or LEFT side. I have 3 columns, each columns show the numbers in text.

In medium device and desktop I  put number on right side using class= "col-md-12 and col-lg-12 text-right" this mean the number will show on RIGHT side of each columns.

In mobile and tablet, I want that number to be show on LEFT side while other two device (medium device and desktop) to show on right side due to auto responsive make smaller.

How can I write code in bootstrap to show the number on column left side and right same same time that depend on device, because each row or column are different align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the bootstrap built class for this task, in this situation we need to solve by adding some code to our CSS. We're going to use some Media Query, let's do it.

First of all, remove the `text-right` class from your element and add an `id="alternate"` in it, it'll looks like that.

```
<div class="col-md-12 and col-lg-12" id="alternate">
   Some Text
</div>
```

Now we are going to do this work in CSS file. This sample of code will control the large and medium devices as desktops and tablets. It will take your text on right when it is accessed from a desktop.

```
#alternate
{
  text-align: right;
}
```

And now we are going do the trick, by adding a media query to control small devices as smartphones. Put this code in the same CSS file. This, will take your text left when it is accessed from a smartphone browser.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

    #alternate
    {
      text-align: left;
    }

}
```

That's it, it willl work.

If you want to control medium devices specifically as it was done with smartphones in media query above. You just add other media query like this.
It will take your text center when it is accessed from medium devices.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

#alternate

     {
       text-align: center;
     }

}
```

-------------------------  For Knowledge ----------------------

In bootstrap documentation you will find this, some media query sizes for several types of devices. Hope you help you.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly what you want to do, but it seems that you need to look into media queries, as they deal with changing css properties depending on the device and/or screen width.

So something like this might help.

```css
.number-text {
 text-align:left;
}
@media (min-width:1025px) {
 .number-text {
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="number-text">
  <p>123</p>
</div>
```